# Ubuntu apps are unable to access internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, proxy

My system is part of an institutional network, and hence I can connect to Internet only by using proxy. I am able to browse the net using browser, and I am also able to able to download from command line using `apt`, as I have already set the proxy settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file.

But, the Ubuntu apps, such as Gmail, GoogleDocs, etc. are unable to access internet. Note that, I am able to access gmail and google docs using my browser. Is there any additional setting that I need to do so that these apps can connect to internet.

Note, that inspite of me being connected to the internet, this is what I see when I open any of these apps :
[image: Network Error Message]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the proxy using the System Settings' Network option?

Comment: @muru No. I didnt. I will try that now.

Comment: @muru It didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

`apt.conf` is the main configuration file for the APT suite of tools, all tools make use of the configuration file. But I don't think that Ubuntu Apps use `apt.conf` for getting proxy settings.

I suggest you to use [Ubproxy](https://code.google.com/p/ubproxy/downloads/detail?name=ubproxy). It is a gui tool to set proxy settings systemwide.

Comment: Sorry till now I was not having access to Internet. I just tried with `Ubproxy` , still this doesn't work.